# Find an exact duplicate by join table field

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a query to find an exact duplicate of the order by its pruducts IDs.

The conditions to find a duplicate are:

1) Order has the same product count.

2) All product IDs are the same.

Tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
SELECT
  order.*,
  count(same_products.id),
  count(all_products.id)
FROM orders
  LEFT JOIN products AS all_products ON all_products.order_id = orders.id
  LEFT JOIN products AS same_products
    ON same_products.order_id = orders.id AND same_products.id IN (30868, 30862)
GROUP BY orders.id
HAVING count(same_products.id) = 4 AND count(all_products.id = 4)
```

Comment: Do you always know what the list of product IDs are?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes

Comment: I don't understand your model. Isn't there a join table betwen product an order? what ist the uniqe key on product? Looks to me ever product can only be in one order?! please post your tables

Answer (score 0):

if you want count duplicated rows you should avoid the all columns (*) selector  because if you have incremental values in your columns  this don't let you find the duplicated .

```
  SELECT
  order.id
  count(same_products.id),
  count(all_products.id)
FROM orders
  LEFT JOIN products AS all_products ON all_products.order_id = orders.id
  LEFT JOIN products AS same_products
    ON same_products.order_id = orders.id AND same_products.id IN (30868, 30862)
GROUP BY orders.id
HAVING count(same_products.id) >1 OR count(all_products.id )> 1
```

and for duplicated row you should check for count> 1 (for both the count)
and be careful with count(all_products.id =4) if you need  to filter for this value you should add  this to the on condition for the related  table eg:

```
  SELECT
  order.id
  count(same_products.id),
  count(all_products.id)
FROM orders
  LEFT JOIN products AS all_products ON all_products.order_id = orders.id and all_products.id =4
  LEFT JOIN products AS same_products
    ON same_products.order_id = orders.id AND same_products.id IN (30868, 30862)
GROUP BY orders.id
HAVING count(same_products.id) >1
```

Comment: It didn't change anything. Why would it, if I group by orders.id anyway?

Comment: Yes  .. grouping by id  ... ...anyway i have  added a suggestion and correct the count(all_products.id = 4) .. let me know what's your real goal ..

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear what you really mean by duplicate, I assume from your description that it's 2 orders with the same products. This seems a little simplistic for example given

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from orders;
+------+---------------------+-------------+
| id   | order_created       | customer_id |
+------+---------------------+-------------+
|    1 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |           1 |
|    2 | 2016-02-01 00:00:00 |           1 |
|    3 | 2016-03-01 00:00:00 |           1 |
|    4 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |           2 |
|    5 | 2016-02-01 00:00:00 |           2 |
|    6 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |           3 |
|   10 | 2016-12-01 00:00:00 |           4 |
+------+---------------------+-------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from order_details;
+----+---------+-----------+------+
| id | orderid | productid | qty  |
+----+---------+-----------+------+
|  1 |       1 |      1213 |   10 |
|  2 |       1 |      9999 |   10 |
|  3 |       2 |      8888 |   10 |
|  4 |       3 |      1213 |   10 |
|  5 |       4 |      2222 |   10 |
|  6 |       5 |      9999 |   30 |
|  7 |       5 |      1213 |   30 |
|  8 |       6 |      9999 |   30 |
|  9 |       6 |      1213 |   30 |
+----+---------+-----------+------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select orders1.*,orders2.*,t.*
from
(select * from
(
select orderid o1orderid,group_concat(productid order by productid) o1grp,sum(qty) qty1
from order_details 
group by orderid
) o1
join
(select orderid o2orderid,group_concat(productid order by productid) o2grp, sum(qty) qty2
from order_details 
group by orderid
) o2
on o2grp = o1grp and qty2 = qty1 and o2orderid > o1orderid
) t
join orders orders1 on t.o1orderid = orders1.id
join orders orders2 on t.o2orderid = orders2.id
```

returns

```
+------+---------------------+-------------+------+---------------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| id   | order_created       | customer_id | id   | order_created       | customer_id | o1orderid | o1grp     | qty1  | o2orderid | o2grp     | qty2  |
+------+---------------------+-------------+------+---------------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------+
|    5 | 2016-02-01 00:00:00 |           2 |    6 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |           3 |         5 | 1213,9999 | 30,30 |         6 | 1213,9999 | 30,30 |
+------+---------------------+-------------+------+---------------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

But customer number is different.